# Convexity of preferences (dissimilar definitions)

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, consumer-theory, preferences, choice-theory

Varian's Intermediate Microeconomics describes convexity as $$\text{Given } x, y \in X: x \sim y \implies \forall t \in [0,1], tx + (1-t)y \succeq x,y$$

The other definition I read everywhere is: $$\text{Given } x, y \in X: x \succeq y \implies \forall t \in [0,1], tx + (1-t) y \succeq y$$

Consider $X = \mathbb{R}^{2}$. The first definition does not imply the second when we have, for example, $U(x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } x_1 + x_2 = 1 \\ 2 \text{ if } x_1 + x_2 > 1 \\ 1 \text{ if } x_1 + x_2 < 1 \end{cases}$.

**Assume $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and preferences are complete, transitive and strictly monotone.** (Strict monotonicity is defined as $y \geq x \ (y \neq x) \implies y \succ x$ where $(y_1, y_2) = y \geq x = (x_1, x_2)$ means $y_1 \geq x \land y_2 \geq x_2$.) **Following are two questions that I thought of and was unable to prove/disprove :**

1. Can we have a preference relation that satisfies the three assumptions and the first definition of convexity but not the second one?
2. Can we have a utility function that describes a preference relation which satisfies the three assumptions and the first definition of convexity but not the second one?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how your utility function satisfies the first definition but not the second? Your notations are also a little inconsistent: In the definitions, $x,y$ are (possibly) vectors, whereas in the utility function, $x,y$ are scalars.

Comment: In the second question, what is the forth assumption: utility representation or continuity of preference?

Comment: @HerrK. I have made the required changes. I hope that suffices.

Comment: @Amit The fourth assumption is the existence of utility representation. I read that utility representation exists iff preferences are complete, transitive and continuous. Since the first two assumptions are already there, I added the fourth assumption (continuity of preferences) for 2.

Comment: @Kur_Kush If preferences are complete, transitive and continuous then the utility representation exists, but the converse is not true. Example utility function $U$ given in the question above represents the discontinuous preference.

Comment: @Amit Okay, that's right. I have made the required changes.

Comment: @Kur_Kush Double implication in the first definition is not very clear. Do you mean: [1] $(\forall x, y)(\forall t)(x\sim y \iff tx+(1-t)y\succsim x, y)$ or [2] $(\forall x, y)(x\sim y \iff (\forall t) tx+(1-t)y\succsim x, y)$ ?

Comment: @Amit Thanks for pointing it out; it's $\implies$ and not $\iff$.

Comment: @Kur_Kush I have updated the answer with the example of a utility function with the desired properties.

Comment: If you are still interested in the edited out question: If preferences are complete, transitive, and continuous, then both definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Yes, please! I initially thought that might be possible, but I couldn't come up with a proof and gave up.

Comment: @Kur_Kush You can try to prove it. Let me tell you one way to approach it: You can proceed by contradiction. Suppose $x\succsim y$, and there exists $t_1$ such that $y \succ t_1x +(1-t_1)y$. Then by continuity, you can find $t_2<t_1$, such that $y \sim t_2x +(1-t_2)y$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @Amit How is $y \sim t_2 x + (1-t_2) y$ by continuity?

Comment: @Kur_Kush The argument to show that such a $t_2$ exists is standard. I have already given you the entire proof. You just need do connect the pieces. Take that as an exercise.

Comment: @Amit By Debreu's theorem, there exists continuous utility function. We have $u(x) > u(z)$, so every value in the interval $[u(z), u(x)]$, one of which happens to be $z = u(y)$, will be attained by the respective $z$-coordinate of the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$. Any idea how to do this without using utility functions, that is, just with the preference relation and from the definitions of continuity?

Comment: @Kur_Kush Of course you can do that without using the utility function. That is the exercise.

Comment: Update: I was able to show without using utility functions (or Debreu and IVT) that the two definitions are equivalent when continuity (rather than monotonicity) is assumed.

Answer (score 3):

**For Q 1**:

Let me give you a preference relation on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$

$(x_1, y_1) \succsim (x_2, y_2)$ if and only if
$(x_1^2 + y_1^2 > x_2^2 + y_2^2)$ or $(x_1^2 + y_1^2 = x_2^2 + y_2^2 \ \wedge x_1 \geq x_2)$

This gives the following strict preference relation:
$(x_1, y_1) \succ (x_2, y_2)$ if and only if
$(x_1^2 + y_1^2 > x_2^2 + y_2^2)$ or $(x_1^2 + y_1^2 = x_2^2 + y_2^2 \ \wedge x_1 > x_2)$

and indifference relation:
$(x_1, y_1) \sim (x_2, y_2)$ if and only if $(x_1=x_2 \wedge y_1 = y_2)$

Clearly, this preference is strictly monotone, 1's definition holds and 2nd does not hold.

Now you can try and construct one on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (there are many)

**For Q 2**:

Let me again give you a utility function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ that satisfy monotonicity, Varian's definition, but does not satisfy definition 2 of convexity. You can try and find an example for $\mathbb{R}^2$ yourself (there are many examples).

\begin{eqnarray*} u(x,y) = \begin{cases} x+ y & \text{if } x + y < 2 \\ 1 + x & \text{if } x + y = 2 \text{ and } x \geq 1 \\ 4 - x & \text{if } x + y = 2 \text{ and } x < 1 \\ x + y + 2 & \text{if } x + y > 2 \end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I tried constructing examples along the lines of these two, but I couldn't. Maybe they have to be constructed differently.

Comment: No you don't need a different construction. I mean of course you can also do a different construction but the above method (with some modifications) will also work.

Comment: Can I please see the counterexample for the $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ case?